# How to calculate crop area within transformable imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, crop

I am getting some problem finding **crop area** for rectangle added as subview on imageview.

Why to add a rectangle over imageview, because I have a requirement that the cropping rectangle should be zoomed with the image. So I did the following..

```
UIView *rectangle;

[self.imageView addSubview:rectangle];
```

Then  adding

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchGesture:)];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

On gesture selector for zoom I have added.

```
-(IBAction)pinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);

    recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

Since the rectangle is on the imageview, it gets zoomed with the imageview.

My problem is how to get the rectangle frame used for cropping, as when I zoom imageview, it changes its frame.

Any help, or hint will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i guess you should not use rectangle as a subview to the image view, although you know the rect area that need to be cropped Rectangle image is just for the reference for the user of the application.. right ?

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446355/crop-a-zoomed-image-in-imageview-inside-scrollview)

It Might help you.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I need to add the rectangle for requirement is as such, by the your link helped me to get the correct crop rect, funny side I had just overlooked the same answer quite while ago..